# Need help implementing a base serializer in DJango

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am trying to implement a base serializer and I am following the "**http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer**".

**My urls.py:**

```
 url(r'^auth/myuser/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/profile/$', UserProfileViewSet.as_view({'patch':'update'}), name='user-profile'),
```

**Views.py:**

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get(self,request,pk,*args,**kwargs):
        user_instance = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dashboard_data = UserProfileSerializer(user_instance)
        content = {'result': dashboard_data}
        return Response(content)
```

**Serializers.py:**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self,obj):
            return{
            'email':obj.email,
            'first_name':obj.first_name,
            'last_name':obj.last_name,
            'date_of_birth':obj.date_of_birth,
            'gender':obj.get_gender_display(),
            'location':obj.location,
            'calling_code':obj.callingcode,
            'phone_primary':obj.phone_primary,
            'phone_secondary':obj.phone_secondary,
            'website':obj.website
            }
```

But I am getting the error "User object is not JSON serializable", and I don't find any attributes of the User obj that are not serializable.

I already found some answers on SO, but I don't find any similar steps in the django rest framework api guide. So looking for a solution that is in sync with the api-guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Serializer:**

It seems what you need is a [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

> The `ModelSerializer` class provides a shortcut that lets you automatically create a `Serializer` class with `fields` that correspond to the Model fields.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have set `fields` attribute to `__all__` to indicate that all the fields in the model are serialized. But, you can also specify which fields to include exaclty:

```
fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',) # etc.
```

**ViewSet:**

The second point is about the `ModelViewSet` where you don't really need to implement the `get` method because it is already implemented for you. You just need to declare the `queryset` and the `serializer_class` just like you have already done:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Comment: I agree and I am sure this works. But I want to try using a Base serializer just to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to render the response in JSON format before returning it.

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get(self,request,pk,*args,**kwargs):
        user_instance = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dashboard_data = UserProfileSerializer(user_instance)
        content = {'result': dashboard_data}
        return JSONResponse(content, status=200)
```

You'll need following imports for this,

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
```

If this doesn't work just try passing dashboard_data to the JSONResponse function